# How to access a TextView from a non-parent file [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I want to access and change the text of a TextView from a non parent file.

This is the class I would like to make the edits from

```
class BarcodeProcessor(graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay, private val workflowModel: WorkflowModel) :
    FrameProcessorBase<List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>>() {
```

In this class there is no onCreat()

Do I need to have AppCompatActivity() in order to gain access to the xml layout files?

Inside this file is where the barcode is processed and I can display the results along with a SQL query to the console, but I want to update the interface to reflect those values. Can I pass them through the companion oject to the parent class?

Is there any way I can make the layout updates from the BarcodeProcessor file?

I've tried including imports

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.barcode_field.*
```

```
    @MainThread
    override fun onSuccess(
        image: FirebaseVisionImage,
        results: List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>,
        graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay
    ) {

        var z = ""
        var isSuccess: Boolean? = false
        //Variables used in the SQL query
        var strData = ""
        var strData2 = ""

        try {
            con = dbConn()      // Connect to database
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Check Your Internet Access!"
            } else {
                val query = "select [ValueOne], [ValueTwo] from [TableName] where [ValueOne] = '$barcodeValue'"
                val stmt = con!!.createStatement()
                val cursor = stmt.executeQuery(query)
                barcodeValue = results[0].getRawValue()!!
                println(barcodeValue)
                if (cursor.next()) {
                    //Selects the values from the columns in the table where the query is taking place
                    strData = cursor.getString("[ValueOne]")
                    strData2 = cursor.getString("[ValueTwo]")
                    var finalDispositionID = strData
                    var moduleSizeID = strData2
                    println(finalDispositionID)
                    println(moduleSizeID)

                    //barcode_field_value3 is the name of the textview
                    //barcode_field_value2 is the name of the other textview

                    //barcode_field_value3.text = strData

                    z = "Login successful"
                    isSuccess = true
                    con!!.close()
                } else {
                    z = "Invalid Credentials!"
                    isSuccess = false
                }
            }
        } catch (ex: java.lang.Exception) {
            isSuccess = false
            z = ex.message!!
        }
```

The query happens in the function onSuccess(). I included the entire file for reference though.

#### LiveBarcodeScanningActivity

````
    private fun setUpWorkflowModel() {
        workflowModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WorkflowModel::class.java)

        // Observes the workflow state changes, if happens, update the overlay view indicators and
        // camera preview state.
        workflowModel!!.workflowState.observe(this, Observer { workflowState ->
            if (workflowState == null || Objects.equal(currentWorkflowState, workflowState)) {
                return@Observer
            }

            currentWorkflowState = workflowState
            Log.d(TAG, "Current workflow state: ${currentWorkflowState!!.name}")

            val wasPromptChipGone = promptChip?.visibility == View.GONE

            when (workflowState) {
                WorkflowState.DETECTING -> {
                    promptChip?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    promptChip?.setText(R.string.prompt_point_at_a_barcode)
                    startCameraPreview()
                }
                WorkflowState.CONFIRMING -> {
                    promptChip?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    promptChip?.setText(R.string.prompt_move_camera_closer)
                    startCameraPreview()
                }
                WorkflowState.SEARCHING -> {
                    promptChip?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    promptChip?.setText(R.string.prompt_searching)
                    stopCameraPreview()
                }
                WorkflowState.DETECTED, WorkflowState.SEARCHED -> {
                    promptChip?.visibility = View.GONE
                    stopCameraPreview()
                }
                else -> promptChip?.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            val shouldPlayPromptChipEnteringAnimation = wasPromptChipGone && promptChip?.visibility == View.VISIBLE
            promptChipAnimator?.let {
                if (shouldPlayPromptChipEnteringAnimation && !it.isRunning) it.start()
            }
        })


        workflowModel?.detectedBarcode?.observe(this, Observer { barcode ->

            if (barcode != null) {
                val barcodeFieldList = ArrayList<BarcodeField>()
                barcodeFieldList.add(BarcodeField("Module Serial Number", barcode.rawValue ?: ""))
                BarcodeResultFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, barcodeFieldList)

            }
        })

    }```
````

Comment: are you using `LiveData` in your app?

Comment: @Fartab yes. When a barcode is scanned it takes the raw value and does a MSSQL query on it and sends back two values. Those values will be displayed inside two TextViews.

Comment: show the code where these two values were retrieved then I can help

Comment: I added the contents of the entire file, but you want to look inside the function onSuccess()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer pertains directly to displaying results in the Google [ML-Kit Showcase](https://github.com/firebase/mlkit-material-android) sample project. So if your working on that with barcode scanning this is related.

In order to display the results on successful scan you need to add the fields into the

#### BarcodeFieldAdapter file

```
    internal class BarcodeFieldViewHolder private constructor(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        private val labelView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.barcode_field_label)
        private val valueView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.barcode_field_value)
        private val moduleSize: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewModuleSize)
        private val finalDisposition: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewFinalDisp)
        private val NCRNotes: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNCR)
        private val OverlapLengthText: TextView = view.findViewById((R.id.textViewOverlapLength))

        fun bindBarcodeField(barcodeField: BarcodeField) {
            //These are the original values that display in the Barcode_field.xml
            labelView.text = barcodeField.label
            valueView.text = barcodeField.value

            //These are the new values I passed in
            moduleSize.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.moduleSize
            finalDisposition.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.finalDisposition
            NCRNotes.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.NCRNotes
            OverlapLengthText.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.OverlapLength
        }
```

Inside

#### BarcodeProcessor

declare a data object

```
    object data {
        var finalDisposition = "init"
        var moduleSize = "init"
        var barcodeValue: String = ""
        var NCRNotes = ""
        var OverlapLength = ""
    }
```

These variables will be passed into the BarcodeFieldAdapter file above then displayed in the barcode_field.xml on success.

Inside the query function - That is in the BarcodeProcessor file

```
//Selects the values from the columns in the table where the query is taking place
                    strData = cursor.getString("Column Name 1")
                    strData2 = cursor.getString("Column Name 2")
                    strData4 = cursor.getString("Column Name 3")

                    //Assigns the values to the variables inside the object data

                    data.finalDisposition = strData
                    data.moduleSize = strData2
                    data.OverlapLength = strData4
                    data.NCRNotes = ""
```

Finally, inside the barcode_field.xml file, create TextViews with the (R.id.TextViewNAMES) that are shown above in the BarcodeFieldAdapter file. Now on successful scanning the new values from the query will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `workflowModel.detectedBarcode` live data in `BarcodeProcessor`. So you can find where you are passing this `workflowModel` to `BarcodeProcessor` constructor and add such a code to observe this live data in your activtiy:

```
workflowModel.detectedBarcode.observe(this, Observer { 
    myTextView.text = it
})
```

Comment: So inside my main "LiveBarcodeScanningActivity.kt" There is a workflow model.         workflowModel?.detectedBarcode?.observe(this, Observer { barcode ->

            if (barcode != null) {
                val barcodeFieldList = ArrayList<BarcodeField>()
                barcodeFieldList.add(BarcodeField("Module Serial Number", barcode.rawValue ?: ""))
                BarcodeResultFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, barcodeFieldList)

            }
        })     can I add the observer under this and change it to my variables holding the query data?

Comment: yeah.. add the answer code to `onCreate` of `LiveBarcodeScanningActivity` below calling `setUpWorkflowModel()`

Comment: It seems that you already observe `detectedBarcode` live data. you can add your code in the existing observer or creating a new observer.

Comment: I added my observer code above. The main portion is at the bottom. For the line ```myTextView.text = it``` would myTextView be the name of the textView in the xml layout? and do I set it equal to the value from the BarcodeProcessor file?

Comment: yes.. this is the same text view in your xml. name it accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify. the ```it``` should that be a value from the BarcodeProcessor file? It comes comes up as a type mismatch leaving it as it.

Comment: I see you named `it` as `barcode`. so do this: `myTextView.text = barcode `

Comment: After a while of experimenting I'm still not able to pass the values through

Comment: what is your problem now? do you have a compile error?

Comment: I just couldn't implement it. I tried the above and then making a new class inside the file to act like a get/set and made them observable but nothing happened with it. Or I would receive ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: barcode_field_value3 must not be null```